# How call from IBM Q Experience (Jupyter Notebook) cplex

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I have the latest version of cplex (12.9) installed on my computer. I use it very well with Jupyter notebook, but in IBM Q Experience, I did not get way to call it. IBM Q Experience warns me that the cplex is not installed. Any ideas?

Many thanks
Parfait

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to import `cplex` within the Jupyter Notebook in IBM Q Experience?

Comment: Hoy could try an alternative Notebook service like Google Colab

Answer (score 0):

As answered on slack, this is not currently possible.

Comment: For reference, can you copy paste the answer provided? It's good to have self-contained answers

Comment: There is no answer to paste as it is not possible.

Comment: Ah, I thought there was background behind why / timeline on implementation.